# IOS7+ UITextView get correct Content Size

Tags: ios, uitableview, contentsize

```
    cell.msgContent.sizeToFit()
    cell.msgContent.layoutIfNeeded()
    let fixedWidth = cell.msgContent.frame.size.width
    cell.msgContent.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.max))
    let newSize = cell.msgContent.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.max))
    var newFrame = cell.msgContent.frame
    newFrame.size = CGSize(width: max(newSize.width, fixedWidth), height: newSize.height)
    cell.msgContent.frame = newFrame
```

cell.msgContent is a `UITextView` which is in a customized `UITableViewCell`. It seems that I can't change the frame of the `UITextView` to the content size.
I've tried another way like use `UITextView.contentSize`, but I can't get the correct size of the content from `UITextView.contentSize`, anyone knows how to get the right size of the content ?  really thanks .

Comment: In what method is the code you posted?

Comment: ah..I've solved this ,thanks a lot for your care ~